# Multiple Schema Flyway

Tags: flyway

I want to create a table on schema TESTE234. The metadata, schema_version table, is on Flyway schema. So I configured:

```
flyway.user=teste234
flyway.password=xxxx
flyway.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxx:1521/xxxx
flyway.schemas=FLYWAY, TESTE234
```

But it´s appear the insufficient privilege message. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The first schema is default schema, so by running in this way, it will try to deploy on `FLYWAY` schema, on which you don't have rights to create anything.
SO options are:

1. give rights to `teste234` on flyway objects
2. Put test234 before FLYWAY: `flyway.schemas=TESTE234, FLYWAY`

Comment: but in case 2, the flyway history tables will be created in the `teste234` schema.